# Letterhead Template translated to Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, template

I've designed a letterhead in illustrator which I am trying to put into Word 2016 so that the client can type out his letters and save them as PDFs.
Page one I will layout as the template looks.

The problem I am having is page 2.

[image]

I would like page two to be margined differently with just the footer displaying. The only way I can think of doing this is to use a page break, but I don't want to send my client a template with two pages and for him to have to print just the page he wants to.

I would like for the page to automatically have no header, the narrow margins of a normal page with the footer remaining.

[image]

Is there a way to do this without burdening the client with making manual edits?

---

2. What is the best setting for the red bar on the left, its and image that has been given a wrap text of tight and positioned where it needed to be. I would like for the bar to remain there (on page 1) without being deleted if all the text was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, and I know this is not ideal I would suggest to use text boxes. This is because if you work the margins in one page the others will have the same margins (I could not find a way to make them differently.) Also I have been struggling with this when I have to make a design into a word template.

Regarding your second question what I usually do as a little trick to make background graphics to stay on their places and increase the chances of them being moved when the client handles the template -  what I do is paste the elements inside the header. Once you are done and close the Header edition mode they will be "locked" (and looking like they lack opacity but that's just Words way of saying it is locked, it will print out fine).

[image: 1]]

As far as the header is concerned you can make it appear only on the first page and not on the second one by ticking the box that says Different First Page on the Header&Footer tab in Word.

[image: 2]]
[image: 3]]

In consequence of all this you will have your red bar and header only on the first page. And it will be locked unless the user chooses to edit the Header. But I assume they won't mess with the header and footer if you  tell them not to.